# Aligning minicolumn with tcolorbox

Tags: minipage, tcolorbox

I'm trying to align two `minipage` environments to the page margins (the left `minipage` to the left margin and the right `minipage` to the right margin) but it does not seem to work. I also need a space between the two `minipage`s and this is why I gave `.45\textwidth` as parameter instead of `.5\textwidth` to the `minipage` environments.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=15mm,bottom=10mm,left=15mm,right=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
    \raggedleft
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    \centering
    \lipsum[1-2]            
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
    \raggedright
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    \centering
    \lipsum[3-4]            
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Could you please tell me how to align the columns?
Below is the output of my example:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Add `\hfill` between the two `minipages`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=15mm,bottom=10mm,left=15mm,right=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
    \raggedleft
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    \centering
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
    \raggedright
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    \centering
    \lipsum[3-4]    
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `tcolorboxes`, you can include them inside a `tcbraster`. By default columns are aligned to left a right margins and inter column space is 2mm, but you can change it with `raster column skip` value:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=15mm,bottom=10mm,left=15mm,right=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster column skip=1cm]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center]
    \lipsum[1-2]            
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center]
    \lipsum[3-4]            
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]